# Why are the apps in "/System/Volumes/Data/Applications" and "/Applications" the same in macOS Catalina?

Tags: macos, alfred, macos-catalina

When I use MacOS Catalina (Public Beta) with [Alfred 4](https://www.alfredapp.com), I find that all the `Applications` installed via the Apple App Store or `brew cask` are duplicated in the candidate list.

Any application in the `/System/Volumes/Data/Applications` will be 
mirrored in `/Applications`.

Does it work as design?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Type `reload﻿` into Alfred.
T﻿his will refresh the app cache for any apps that may no longer exist in the old location.﻿
Reference: https://www.alfredforum.com/topic/13121-duplicate-apps-in-results-1015-and-v4/